# Python datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) showing time relative to PC custom time

Tags: python, datetime, time, utc

The problem is really simple. I'm trying to get the UTC hour on python:

```
from datetime import timezone

now = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
print(now)
print(now.strftime("%A %H:%M"))

>>2018-03-16 18:28:11.166272+00:00
>>Friday 18:28
```

So far so good, but when I test my code on a computer with a manually adjusted time (not a different timezone or daylight saving setting), let's say, 2 hours ahead. The same code return this.

```
>>2018-03-16 20:54:11.166272+00:00
>>Friday 20:54
```

No matter what UTC or timezone options I try, I can't seem to get rid of that time offset.
I'm about to just modify my code so the time is retrieved from a "non time adjusted computer" and work from there, but I'm sure there must be other way in python.

Yes, english is not my first language. Thanks in advance.

PD: If it's of any help, the PC with the adjusted time is running windows. And no, if you think I can just go and fix it's time settings, it won't happen. I don't have access to it .

Comment: You have two systems with completely different ideas of what time it is. There's no way to get a consistent answer from both of them without correcting the one that's wrong.

Comment: At the time of the post:
My pc  15:28
Adjusted pc  17:54

Comment: Let's say I know the exact offset of that other PC. How can I fix it? Because the other problem would be: How python knows that the original time has been altered.

Comment: Python doesn't know that the original time has been altered. It only knows what time the system says it is. If you know the offset, you can correct for it via the usual `datetime`/`timedelta` arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, but if I correct it. It will correct it for every one that run that code. So I can't just subtract those 2 ish hours. Because while it would fix the adjusted PC, My PC would also subtract those 2 ish hours (basically returning to the original problem)

Comment: Correct. If you're relying on system time, you're relying on that time being correct. If you can't rely on the system time being correct, you'll need to look into making an NTP query or some such.

Comment: So that's how it is. Well, thanks for your time glibdud!